# Why do node.js create multiple process

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pid

I'm kinda new to node.js but when I launch my node.js server (a simple web app) and after using it once it always create 6 processes (with the same name), I'm using websockets through socket.io do you think this is the reason ?
Thank you !

http://imgur.com/Zknttl0

No I am not using cluster :p I'm not gonna give you the whole code (way to long) but here are the modules I use (its a copy/paste from my package.json file):

"body-parser": "latest",

```
"express": "latest"

"ejs" : "latest",

"cookie-session" : "latest",

"request" : "latest",

"goo.gl" : "latest",

"nodemon" : "latest",

"socket.io" : "latest",

"ent" : "latest",

"serve-favicon" : "latest",

"express-session" : "latest",

"socket.io-express-session" : "latest",

"session-file-store" : "latest",

"easyimage" : "latest"
```

About nodemon whether I use it or not when I start the app I still have 6 processes.

Thx for looking into it !

Comment: do you use `cluster` module? Or some process managers like `forever` or `supervisor`? Show your server.js file

Comment: In addition, do  you use some framework?